# What are null cells?

Tags: hematology, stem-cells, histology

My histology textbook says the following:

> The pluripotential hemopoietic stemm cell (which resembles a lymphocyte) is a member of the null cell population of lymphocytes.

It then goes on to add:

There are three types of lymphocytes:

- T cells
- B cells
- Null cells:

  - Pluripotential hemopoietic stem cells
  - Natural Killer cells

However, this is the only text I find that classifies Pluripotential hemopoietic stem cells as null cells. 
My question is: what are null cells? (and is this textbook accurate)

Thank you,
jsx

Comment: When quoting, can you please make sure to quote exactly what is being said? It is part of academic ethics to not misquote (but typos happen, don't worry about it). I doubt your textbook says `stemm cell` and by this small typo of yours , it makes me wonder whether `(which resembles a lymphocyte)` was added by you or was in the original quotation. You also want to cite which textbook it is (and eventually add a link to it). Are the bullets a direct quote as well? If yes, you should start the lines with `>` to highlight that it is a quote.

Comment: This seems like either a very basic, very old, or very misleading textbook. The obvious meaning of "null cell" here is one that lacks both B cell receptors and T cell receptors. Such "null cells" would cover vastly more territory than the two sets mentioned, which is why I question the accuracy of the book.

Comment: Did you have a look at [wikipedia > null cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_cell)?

Comment: @iayork I understand that that is the definition of a null cell. I'm using Gartner's 'Colour Atlas and Text of Histology'. So, null cells are simply cells that lack the receptors that T and B cells possess, and as such include the natural killer cells, killer cells, PHSCs and other cells too?

Comment: @jxs As far as I know it's obsolete terminology. It probably included all those, but just by accident, just as "horseless carriage" would include a Tesla and a Ferrari as well as a Model T.

Comment: @iayork That was my impression. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: This is easily found with a simple google search. "What are null cells"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_cell

Comment: @akaDrHouse as the term is virtually obsolete (and was previously used to refer to what we now call natural killer cells and killer cells), I was simply confused as to whether PHSCs truly belong to this classification. The text is misleading in that the pluripotential stem cell which gives rise to all the blood cells is then found again as a subtype of a subgroup it itself generated. I wouldn't come to ask a question before a google search.

Answer (score 1):

Null cells are a "slang term" for cells of the lymphocyte progeny that are not APC (antigen presenting cells) and lack T and B cell receptors - therefore they are the natural killer (NK) cells.